# Back button is not visible in Navigation Bar in iPhone OS 4.0 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationbar, back

In my application (View based), the back buttons are not visible in the navigation bar. If I click that button, the actions works properly. It's very weird to me. The back button is visible and properly working in iPhone OS 3.0 and others.(Except OS 4.0). I am currently working in iPhone OS 4.0.

Here is my code:

```
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] init];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 70, 0, 20)];
UIBarButtonItem *b=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];    
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=b;
[b release];
[btn release];
```

Note: It doesn't work only iPhone OS 4.0. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you replace this code wherever you want and its working fine in OS 4.0.

```
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40)];

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40)];

[myView addSubview:btn];

UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,50,30)];

[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"]];

[myView addSubview:myImage];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(lOut) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *b1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myView];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = b1;

[btn release];

[b1 release];

[myView release];

[myImage release];
```

I hope it will help ypu.

Comment: Hello good morning ,i am having same problem it still does not work on  ios 4.3. I am using 2 codes 1st to set custom uinavigation bar like this :

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[navBar viewWithTag:1];
        if (imageView == nil)
        {
            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"]];
            [imageView setTag:1];
            [navBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
            [imageView release];
        }
and then the code you sent.. Any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 40)];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info44.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info44_glowing.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];   
[btn addTarget:[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]  action:@selector(settingAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *settingButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingButton;
[btn release];
[settingButton release];
```