# How can I write the actions for image view when touch it in iPhone-OS 4.0

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, touch

I want to display the image in navigation bar instead of a back button with an action. So now I have used image view and displayed the image in the navigation bar. Now I want to write the actions for image view, when touch or click the image view. Is it possible to write an action for image view?

I am currently working in iPhone OS 4.0.

Please see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124110/back-button-is-not-visible-in-navigation-bar-in-iphone-os-4-0-in-iphone).

Here is my code:

```
     UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,40,40)];
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view1];
     view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"];
     UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
     [view1 addSubview:imgView];
```

How can I write the actions for image view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before iOS 3.2, nou would need a sublass of UIImageView and implement the touch handlers.
Or replace your UIImageView with a UIButton with custom type.

With iOS 3.2+, [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what gets your things done efficiently - just add the appropriate one to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add views directly to the navigation bar unless you're prepared for it to break in a future OS release.

```
UIButton * b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
b.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"];
b.frame = (CGRect){{0,0},{40,40}};
[b addTarget:self action:@selection(wahatever) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:b] autorelease];
```